# clickhouse AggregatingMergeTree TTL set aggregated values

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to make aggregated table with TTL. But looks like not possible to set new values for  columns with AggregateFunction type.
I have simple example table for inserts:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS basic_test_table;
CREATE TABLE basic_test_table (
    ts DateTime comment 'timestamp',
    n UInt32 comment 'generated integer',
    s String comment 'generated 1-letter string',
    t String comment 'TOP|RARE'
)
Engine = MergeTree
ORDER BY ts;
```

and aggregated table with materialized view:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS agg_basic_table;
CREATE TABLE agg_basic_table (
    ts DateTime,
    n_avg AggregateFunction(avg, Float32) comment 'simple average',
    n_sum SimpleAggregateFunction(sumWithOverflow, UInt32) comment 'simple sum',
    n_rate Float32 materialized n_sum / 60.0 comment 'its not working',
    s_uniq AggregateFunction(uniq, String) comment 'count of uniq strings',
    t_top AggregateFunction(anyHeavy, String) comment 'most frequent string'
)
engine AggregatingMergeTree()
order by (toStartOfTenMinutes(ts), ts)
ttl ts + interval 10 minute
group by toStartOfTenMinutes(ts) set
    ts = min(toStartOfTenMinutes(ts)),
    n_avg = avg(n_avg), //problem here
    n_sum = sum(n_sum), //it works because we use SimpleAggregateFunction
    n_rate = avg(n_rate),//problem here
    s_uniq = uniqMerge(s_uniq), //problem here
    t_top = anyHeavyMerge(t_top); //problem here

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mv_agg_basic;
create materialized view if not exists mv_agg_basic to agg_basic_table
    as select
        toStartOfMinute(b.ts) as ts,
        avgState(b.n::Float32) as n_avg,
        sum(b.n::UInt32) as n_sum,
        uniqState(b.s) as s_uniq,
        anyHeavyState(b.t) as t_top
    from basic_test_table b
    group by (ts)
    order by (ts);
```

generate some data:

```
insert into basic_test_table (ts, n, s, t)
select now() + interval (5000 - number) second, intDiv(number, 1000) + 1, randomFixedString(1), if(number % 10 >= 4, 'TOP', 'RARE') from numbers(10000) settings max_block_size=10000;
```

and select from aggregated table

```
select ts, avgMerge(n_avg), sum(n_sum), avg(n_rate), uniqMerge(s_uniq), anyHeavyMerge(t_top) from agg_basic_table group by ts order by ts;
```

I would like to get result with timestamps(with 1m interval for recent data and 10m interval for other), average of value n, sum of value n, rate of value n, number of uniq strings in s, most popular string in t.
It works without TTL(except rate field - can't calculate it properly. If I'm insert 1 value per second with value 1 - it's shows 1, if I'm do same insert twice - it's shows 1 again, but it must be 2).
Is using AggregateFunction with -State and -Merge functions only one way to make aggregating table?